# Symfony3 behaves weird when uploading an image

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a form which should save an image to a `BLOB` column in my database.

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name', TextType::class)
      ->add('type', TextType::class)
      ->add('category', TextType::class)
      ->add('url', TextType::class)
      ->add('seoText', TextareaType::class, array(
          'attr' => array('rows' => 15)
      ))
      ->add('file', FileType::class)
      ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Opslaan'));
}
```

Firstly, the unexpected behaviour I am finding is when my WYSIWYG editor is in HTML editing mode. If it is, Symfony validation will tell me there's a field missing and when I switch back to WYSIWYG mode, it will all be fine.

Finally, I created an extra field in the model `private $file` with the getters and setters. I also created an extra method `upload` like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }          
    $strm = fopen($this->file->getRealPath(), 'rb');
    $this->setImage(stream_get_contents($strm));
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
/**
 * Create a new page.
 * @Route("/pages/new", name="new_page")
 * @Method(methods={"GET", "POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $page = new EnrichedPages();
    $form = $this->createForm(EnrichedPageType::class, $page);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Is this form submitted and valid? Then get Doctrine to create it.
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($page);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('all_pages');
    }

    return $this->render(':pages:new.html.twig', array(
        'page' => $page,
        'newPageForm' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

The doctrine.DEBUG logs tell me there is still a `null` value, which also shows up in my database. What am I doing wrong here?